# Apollo-11 AGC core memory has 5 wires per core (rather than 3 or 4) - why?

Tags: apollo-program, history, flight-computer, apollo-11, data-storage

Apollo-11 AGC core memory has 5 wires per core (rather than 3 or 4) - why?
I am referring to this image in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Guidance_Computer#/media/File:Apollo_1024_bit_core_memory_module.jpg
Peering closely, I see x and y lines that address individual rows and columns of cores.  Then I see 3 more lines: one diagonal line that threads all the cores; one line that runs up and down and appears to thread all the cores;  one line that runs back and forth across and appears to thread all the cores.  Usually there are just one or two such lines (sense/inhibit combined or separate sense & inhibit lines) that thread all the cores on a plane.  Any ideas why?

Comment: See also this related [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33143/bits-per-core-for-the-different-versions-of-the-apollo-guidance-computer-core-ro?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

The document [General Design Characteristics of the Apollo Guidance Computer](http://klabs.org/history/history_docs/mit_docs/1009.pdf) shows 4 wires per "donut".

> One  core,  threaded  by  four  wires  stores  a  bit.  Two  wires 
>   select,  one  writes,  and  one  senses.

[image]

Note: this is for the erasable memory, as shown in the image you linked. If I am interpreting the document correctly, the read-only memory had 3 wires per "donut".

Comment: Thanks, that's a wonderful document that I had not seen.  The Wikipedia article on the AGC refers to a Block II redesign in 1966.  Are there any similar historical documents on the Block II design?

Comment: There are a number of other documents linked at the wonderful but slowly deteriorating klabs page: http://klabs.org/history/history_docs/mit_docs/agc.htm

Answer (score 4):

The Wikipedia photo is definitely not an AGC core memory. The AGC's memory (both block I and block II) was very compact, and the plane was folded accordion-style to fit in the rectangular module. The AGC's erasable core memory had 4 wires through each core: horizontal and vertical X/Y select lines, a diagonal sense line, and vertical inhibit line. Each AGC plane was 2048 bites in a 64×32 matrix.

As for the core plane in the Wikipedia, it looks familiar, but I don't know what it is from.

I've studied the AGC memory closely; my writeup (with X-rays) is [here](http://www.righto.com/2019/01/inside-apollo-guidance-computers-core.html) if you want details of its construction.

Comment: You've put together a very valuable source there, Ken!  I guess there will be no good image for the wikipedia page since the erasable memory is potted.  I didn't spot a link from the wikipedia AGC page to your page.  I can certainly add one if that's OK.