# Given small computational resources, how was navigation implemented? (Not samples of old guidance software)

Tags: navigation, software

**Update 2** :  The youtube vidoe [How did NASA Steer the Saturn V](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dI-JW2UIAG0) answers this question and then some, a must watch.

**Update**: I really wanted to know how spacecraft navigation (not guidance) computers worked, given small computational resources. I have asked in [another question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/samples-of-old-guidance-software-not-with-small-computational-resources-implem) and edited this question to limit answers to examples of old guidance software source code, For those interested in samples of old guidance software please refer to [Samples of old guidance software using computational resources on Earth implementing navigation in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/samples-of-old-guidance-software-not-with-small-computational-resources-implem) instead. Leaving the original (incorrect question below as it was in order to not make the responses look irrelevant).

In an article I came across the something like "X used hardware programme for Venus mission with 65 KB (not sure if this number is correct?) memory".

I am a software developer and with all the resources available today I cannot fathom where one could even start such an endeavour.

Is there an archive (museum) of old/antique software that was written (hard or soft) for interplanetary missions? if something at a higher level than assembly or the equivalent in today's Java, Pascal, C#, etc. programming languages with no consideration for memory and disk usage then that would be even better.

From what little I understood it seems a task equivalent to construction of  pyramids with primitive tools. Are there any simulation or tools to get a today's simpleton programmer a glimpse and appreciation of what those giants did?

Comment: not an answer, but links in answers to the following questions might be helpful: [How did the Apollo computers evaluate transcendental functions like sine, arctangent, log?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30952/12102) as well as [How did the Apollo guidance computer handle parity bit errors?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35934/12102) and also [How did the Apollo guidance computer handle the Earth-Moon system's rotation around the Sun?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34294/12102)

Comment: Exchanging information for devices that are "inherently capable of delivering nuclear weapons" is generally frowned upon. IIRC, there's treaties against it.

Comment: @Mazura what is the relationship between guiding to Venus or Mars have to do with nuclear weapons ? Many two bit countries have access to missile guidance software. This question is about how the hell somebody can make hardware program with 65kb where windows notepad is 244kb . What is wrong with that ?

Comment: The relationship is both 'space probes' and ICBMs need to leave earth first. - "Samples of old guidance software" for a Saturn-V... you *will not* find.

Comment: @Mazura that's cool , was only after some explanation for how the hell with 65KB one can guide a interplanetary probe when windows notepad is 244KB , I assumed it can detect its position relative to sun or to its final destination Mars , Neptune , Venus, what ever. The amount of calculations required is way too much for a small program. Thanks to the accepted answer the mystery is solved , it is a guidence system and not navigation. I mistook it that it also does navigation as well as guidance. Guidance system is simple control systems.

Comment: @Arjang, orbital-transfer software might not be suitable for ICBMs, but I'm pretty sure the Apollo re-entry guidance software is.

Comment: @Mark thank you , wasn't Apollo guided by the astronauts? I didn't think that was fully automated. My starting point was when I heard about reachability theory , or how did they know that they can land two Mars probes on the opposite sides of the Mars.

Comment: @Arjang To be honest, the current accepted answer does not answer the question "Samples of old guidance software". I suggest that you either edit the question so it better reflects what you really wanted to know (how spacecraft guidance computers work, given small computational resources) or ask that in a another question and edit this question to limit answers to examples of old guidance software source code. In this way future visitors will find what they expect from the question title.

Comment: Even something simple like notepad has a whole host of OS compatibility layers, the gui and other libraries it's built on... It's written in a fairly high level language, targeted to the fairly complex x86 platform and has a surprising amount of functionality.  When you get down to assembly and optimising for size, you can do incredible things - e.g. https://www.theverge.com/2012/5/14/3014698/assembly-4k-demoscene-fractals

Comment: Tiny processors are still alive and well; you probably own several, especially if you have a car. For example, the [PIC10 family of chips](https://www.microchip.com/paramchartsearch/chart.aspx?branchID=1009) have up to a whopping 896 bytes of code storage, and 64 bytes (yes, bytes) of RAM! If you're buying in bulk, they cost around 30 cents each.

Comment: @Ludo : Yes, you are right, I am adding an Edit note. I'm afraid to edit the question as from other SE sites I have leaned that it is not fair to make the replies to the original question to look irrelavent.

Comment: @Baldrickk : holy hell, yes that is more like it, I had no idea why one would try to save space on a PC, let alone there are competitions for it. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @Arjang, apart from Apollo 13, the manual flying during Apollo consisted of 1) final touchdown on the Moon, 2) docking of the Command Module and Lunar Module, and 3) various minor attitude changes.  Atmospheric re-entry, in particular, was fully automated, although they practiced manual procedures just in case the guidance computer stopped working.

Comment: Nobody 'flew' the Space Shuttle either. And yet, people whine about others using MechJeb (auto pilot) in Kerbal Space Program.

Comment: Claiming the title of "software developer" while not understanding how efficient code can solve small problems is more than a little dubious, and perhaps evident of how *inefficient* a lot of current habits are.  There's really no substitute for understanding the *problem* and understanding the *machine* that is available to solve it.

Comment: As a programmer I strongly encourage you to try microcontroller programming. An Arduino is a great introduction. The basic model has 1k of RAM. You'd be amazed at how much you can achieve with 1k of RAM. People have written everything from quadcopter (drone) controllers, radio-control receivers, walking robot controllers to airplane autopilot guidance/navigation software all in 1k of RAM. I started microcontroller programming with the PIC16F84 which has 68 bytes (yes, bytes, not kilobytes) of RAM and I implemented a lot of projects with it.

Comment: You're too young, you don't realize what we used to do in the old days with minimal memory.  Without all the baggage of modern programs and libraries and when writing in assembly you can do a lot with very little memory, very often the data takes a lot more than the code.  I've written multiple useful programs under 1k.

Comment: Machine code that cares for absolutely nothing but the job at hand is awesome powerful. Even olde 8 bit microprocessors worked wonders. A friend wrote a basketball scoring program that drove two numeric score displays, kept track of scores and time keeping and somewhat more in 512 **BYTES**. | I once could input on a hex keypad the machine code (not assembler) for an alphanumeric (of sorts) moving message program displayed on a 7 segment numeric multiplexed display plus its message "out of my head". Probably a few dozen bytes of actual code. [86DD, B70120, CE.... - :-) ]

Comment: @Mazura every shuttle landing was flown by hand.

Comment: @Mazura : Does that mean that size of guidance program for shuttle was 0 bytes ( not needed ). I guess all the navigation was done by the ground.

Comment: [What operating system(s) were used in the space shuttle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/19006/what-operating-systems-were-used-in-the-space-shuttle) - The whole thing ran on 400k lines of code. IIRC the PASS that ran on the 4 cpus was ~40k lines. The BFS was 1000 lines of code, never used, that could have done it. Both of those were probably the best programs ever written. ( "It's also not quite correct that it was "never used" - its SM functions were used during ascent and entry." – Organic Marble)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In many of the early probes, up until close to Apollo there were not true computers on space probes. All computing was done on Earth and the onboard electronics was known as a sequencer, for Pioneer 10 it had 222 possible commands 5 of which could be readied. Early Venus probes sent data by mechanically switching different sensors to modulate a CW transmitter in turn and sorting it all apart on Earth.

This also applied to much of the Apollo launch process, where the hardware in the [launch platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Launcher_Platform) did not run true software but a sequence (from [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319177885)) of 'wait, activate this, wait, measure that and if out of bounds hold else continue'.

Along with the AGC code link by Ludo you can look at the [abort controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Abort_Guidance_System) as a smaller scale example of how things were done (fixed loop of known steps and timing).

Even today it is very rare to send code to a space craft that does not boil down to a sequence of very specific instructions to be run in order. Curiosity has some autonomous navigation and photo taking capability but generally branching code is there to trigger fallback/fail safe 'oops stop, solve antenna pointing problem and call home for instructions' rather than AI or learning code.

In general terms code was made to fit the same way people program for microcontrollers today:

Not having any form of user interface in code (Apollo DSKY was largely hardware)

Using approximation or integer math over floating point (lots of things are possible where pi = 3) or precompute constants on Earth and upload when required (say gravity or engine performance)

Custom designing supporting hardware like [star trackers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_tracker#Star_tracker) to be preloaded with constants from Earth and to output pre formatted and bound checked for the next processing step.
In fact, bounds check only once, where data is sourced and ensure no following step can overflow it.

Design algorithms to work in register(s) rather than memory locations (which makes horrible source since you do not have variables) but means you can avoid lots of moving values in and out of memory.

Avoid general problems for the specific, for space craft this was all about navigation, reporting sensor/instrument states and pointing. All of these could have carefully crafted code that worked well over a specific range of inputs ([Though see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure)).

Trust your data (in security sense) ([though nature can still get you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_hardening#Examples_of_rad-hard_computers))

Comment: _"Curiosity has some autonomous navigation and photo taking capability but generally branching code is there to trigger fallback/fail safe 'oops stop, solve antenna pointing problem and call home for instructions' rather than AI or learning code."_ Well, Mars Pathfinder (from the 90s) had a real-time operating system ([VxWorks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxWorks)) with sufficent complexity of task schedule that it could run into a [priority inversion problem](https://www.rapitasystems.com/blog/what-really-happened-to-the-software-on-the-mars-pathfinder-spacecraft). Complex, Complex.

Comment: You don't need a computer that can run *Space War* when you're flying a real spaceship :)

Answer (score 27):

*(originally answered to "Samples of old guidance software")*

The first that comes to mind is the [Github repository of the Apollo 11 Guidance Computer (AGC)](https://github.com/chrislgarry/Apollo-11). The repository has both Command Module and Lunar Module software, but note that it is transcribed from hardcopies, so it might not be fully complete (yet). You can find a simulator of the AGC on the [Virtual AGC website](http://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/) (there's a ton of other references there also).

Answer (score 15):

> I am a software developer and with all the resources available today I cannot fathom where one could even start such an endeavour.

There are plenty of computer-based systems to this day that have to live with such limitations. There are plenty of embedded systems where 2^16 (65536) bytes of memory remains a luxury. After all, on machines that use 16 bit memory addresses (plenty of which still exist and are plenty of which are still manufactured to this day), there's no point in having over 65636 bytes of memory. And just as there's no problem with a computer with 64 bit addresses having less than 18+ exabytes of memory, there's no problem with a computer that uses 16 bit addresses having less than 2^16 bytes of memory.

There are many ways to start with such an endeavor. The number one rule is to eschew the use of an operating system. Many (most?) embedded systems are [bare machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine). There's no OS, and there's only one program running, ever. Your microwave oven has a computer operating as an embedded system, and it has no operating system. If your car was manufactured in the last 25+ years, it has lots of embedded systems running in it. If your car is anywhere close to modern, it has several dozens of microcontrollers that collectively run several million lines of code.

Many of the microcontrollers in a modern car are not subject to the 64K (2^16, or 65536) address limit. Back in the day, that was a very common limit, and it inherently limited the size of memory. But it did not limit storage. The problem of having disk size exceed address limitations was solved in the 1950s and 1960s. A common solution was to use [memory overlays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_(programming)). This technique, one I'm glad to have (mostly) forgotten about, remains common to this day in embedded systems programming.

Another widely used technique was and is to have the embedded machine follow a [Harvard architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard_architecture) as opposed to a [von Neumann architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture). There is no distinction between code and data in a Von Neumann machine. Code and data are very different things in a Harvard architecture machine, possibly with different word sizes. Your laptop or desktop machine most likely is a von Neumann architecture machine, at least on the surface. Deep under the hood it looks more like a Harvard machine, with separate caches for code and data.

Comment: Yes, I should have said application developer on PCs with (almost) unlimited amounts of everything, forgot about the embedded systems and all their challenges for a extremely limited memory and storage. Shouldn't be throwing around "I am a software developer" so lightly.

Comment: When I was a physics student the HP-25 came out; it could hold 49 program steps. I programmed it to act as a lunar lander, where the user entered burn duration and thrust. All the physical constants, lander mass, fuel mass, initial velocity, and altitude were correct. I ignored attitude / vector control, but the point is that it was *49 steps* and correct. And it was damn hard to land. Neil Armstrong was one hell of a pilot!

Answer (score 3):

The way it was implemented in the ICBM world was that you had six fellows sitting around a table designing the mathematical routines and overall architecture, the program component's detailed coding, and the computer hardware all at the same time. Five lines of code per day was considered a good day's work. Most of the time was spent arguing about whether to do something with hardware or software. Integrated circuits had advanced to the point of four-bit registers being available. They were used for the cpu's two registers.

There was no addressable memory in the system I worked on. Just a disk with a bunch of fixed heads. The code was clocked to the disk. There was an upper and lower bus and two registers of one word length, but it was a big word.

There ended up being four programs that could be swapped using remote data change. Only one was for flight, the others were ground programs.

Hardware did most of the work, things like 3 x 3 matrix math were done with a few microcode instructions that resulted in a new matrix replacing an old one in the same location on the disk.

The cpu often had areas that weren't being used during these longer intructions, so they could sneak little additions/subtractions/multiplications/divisions in the middle. These intructions only switched small pieces of the cpu, and there were LOTS of instructions available. You just had to make sure everything was in the right place on the disk so that it was available when there was a bit of free time. They had five different instructions for dividing two numbers, differing only in the route and timing of the process within cpu to avoid colliding with other ongoing computations. A lot of the bookkeeping functions got done this way.

The really fun part was that you could start a long instruction before you had all the numbers to complete it. While it was grinding on the front end, you could initiate an addition operation and leave it in a register for the long instruction to find later. You might even be able to write it to the disk. These were a real joy to trace and debug.

The nav computer had to drive three output signals to steer the rocket. It knew nothing about staging or anything else. It had a table that said it should see accelerometer counts of x,y,z at time t (accumulated pulses equaled accelerometer axis velocity). It compared the actual counts to the preprogrammed table and calculated new steering signals.

The bottom line is that the programmers had a pretty limited goal and had a complete map of the cpu in their head and could follow the entire cpu operation in their head as the program components were executed.

I wasn't in on the design phase, but was trained on the cpu and microcode by one of the guys that sat at the table.

Comment: Interesting. Which missile was this for?

Comment: Minuteman. At the time of it's roll out, the computer systems in MM represented more than half of the world's floating point computational power. There were actually several different parts to the system. In addition to the flight computer, there was a ground computer in each silo, and a different one in each command capsule, plus the ones that cut the telemetry tapes. The system used the same hardware until SAC was disbanded, which is when I left.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the FORTH language. It makes no distinction between user code and the code in the (tiny) OS kernel. It was used in the firmware of early satellites.
A good description is here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_(programming_language)

Comment: This is close to being a "link only answer"

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read this book:
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7754526-the-apollo-guidance-computer

The first half is a detailed description of the hardware architecture of the Apollo Guidance Computer and the software that ran on it. There are some fascinating discussions of the limitations of the hardware and what the designers did to overcome those limitations.